# SQLite error Android - Index -1 requested

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get some data from my DB, but i get next error:

```
Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

here is my code:

```
sUri = DB_Contract.ChatListEntry.buildUriForCurrentRoom(sNewMessageRoomId);
        sCursor = sActivity.getContentResolver().query(sUri, sChatProjection, null, null, null);

        messageCount = sCursor.getInt(NEW_MESSAGE_COUNT) + 1;
```

I got this error when trying to get messageCount;

Comment: write `sCursor.moveToFirst(); ` before messageCount line

Answer (score 6):

you have to move your cursor in a valid position, before accessing it. Try calling

```
sCursor.moveToFirst();
```

before using `getInt`. E.g.

```
if (sCursor.moveToFirst()) {
   messageCount = sCursor.getInt(NEW_MESSAGE_COUNT) + 1;
}
```